# unable to get content

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am unable to get content from tiny mce text editor. I'm trying to post it to firestore when click there is an error. If I don't post description it works fine.

```
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

 function Category(){
         <div>

              <Editor
                         apiKey=''
                         initialValue=""
                         value={description} 
                         onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                         init={{
                           height: 400,
                           menubar: true,
                           plugins: [
                             'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                             'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                             'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
                           ],
                           toolbar:
                             'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline  link backcolor | \
                             alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
                             bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat '
                         }}
                         
                             />
                          {description}

      </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` property on `e.target` in this instance, but there is a `getContent` property that has a function as a value that you can use to retrieve the text.

So you can do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <Editor
        apiKey=""
        initialValue=""
        value={description}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setDescription(e.target.getContent({ format: "text" }))
        }
        init={{
          height: 400,
          menubar: true,
          plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount"
          ],
          toolbar:
            "undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline  link backcolor | \
                   alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
                   bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat "
        }}
      />
      {description}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`{format: "text"}` is passed to the `getContent` function so it doesn't include the tags around the text. If you also want to include the tags around the text you can omit this.

Comment: how will I get toollbar features like there is link in text it won't push

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Links are saved to the state just fine.

Comment: I mean if I am using features from plugin like bold, link how will I store this.

Comment: Then like I mentioned you can remove `{format: "text"}` as parameter from the `getContent` function call and you will be able to distinguish from text type by tag.